# sql script hangs in SQLplus on Solaris

Tags: sqlplus, solaris

Running an sql script in SQLplus on Solaris
Any idea why script hangs in line 9 '/' and not executed?

```
declare
 dummy number;
begin

 select 1 
 into dummy from dual ;  

end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you committed or rolled back the transaction? It seems like transaction isn't committed.

You just need to either add an `exit` at the end of the script, or run it as `sqlplus username/password@server/dbname < Setup.sql` (i.e. redirected input, **< instead of @**).

You can check if that's the issue by just typing '`exit`' in the hanging session.

Answer (score 0):

May be due to invisible characters, which could come from a wrong FTP copy.
Maybe because you don't have a newline after the last slash ?
Try removing empty lines inside the complete PL/SQL block.